# Parse feed java

Tags: java, xml

I´m using rome.jar to parse Wordpress feed with java like this:

```
public class RSSReader {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url  = new URL("http://ayudawp.com/feed/");
    XmlReader reader = null;

    try {

      reader = new XmlReader(url);
      SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedInput().build(reader);


     for (Iterator i = feed.getEntries().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        SyndEntry entry = (SyndEntry) i.next();
        System.out.println(entry.getTitle());
        System.out.println(entry.getDescription());
        System.out.println(entry.getContents());
        System.out.println(entry.getPublishedDate());
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

but when I do the System.out.println of the entry.getContent() I don´t see all the content of the new. Any solution please? My feed code has  format

Comment: I see some part of the feed and later puts "Continue reading"

Comment: Is what appears to have the feed: http://ayudawp.com/feed/ Have you tried to use another feed?

Comment: Seems you get the teaser of the entries. Look into your SyndEntry, if there is some link to the full article and call it's feed.

Comment: Thank you,I´m novice , I don´t understand what is SyndEntry, can you explain me? :)

Comment: How can I get the value of ContentModuleImpl.contents[0]?

Answer (score 0):

I have find a better solution to parse feed:

http://oneplaceinfo.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/java-code-to-parse-the-rss-feed-for-any-wordpress-blog/